# Linking header files to an implementation file in C++

Tags: c++

I had a particular question regarding linking files in C++. Say I have a header file named fmttime.h and i want to link it to fmttime.cc (Implementation file) heres what I've done so far

```
 ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime);
 int main()
 {
     struct timeval tv;
     struct ExpandedTime etime;
     gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
     localTime(&tv,&etime);

 }

 ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime)
 {
     tzset(); // Corrects timezone

     int epochT = (tv->tv_sec) - timezone; // Epoch seconds with
     int epochUT = tv->tv_usec;  // Timezone correction

     int seconds = epochT % 60;
     epochT /= 60;
     etime->et_sec = seconds;
     etime->et_usec = epochUT;

     int minutes = epochT % 60;
     epochT /= 60;
     etime->et_min = minutes;

     int hours = (epochT % 24) + daylight; // Hours with DST correction
     epochT /= 24;
     etime->et_hour = hours;

     printf("%d,%d,%d\n", seconds, minutes, hours);
     printf("%d\n", epochUT);
     printf("%d\n", timezone);
     printf("%d\n", daylight);
     return etime;
 }
```

So basically I've included fmttime.h in the header as so. I have a few questions about this whole process. In the fmttime.h all I have is this function prototype (Which is all that is actually needed for my purposes).

```
 // Interface file for fmttime.h which is including the fmttime.c
 // Contains function prototype

 char* formatTime(struct timeval* tv, char* buf, size_t len);
```

Now if I want to use this function in my fmttime.cc implementation file do I need to redeclare the function prototype? Or can it be skipped due to the header file already having it included and thus included in fmttime.cc since there are linked through #include.

So I basically want to add into the .CC file char* formatTime (struct timeval*.....) but am not sure if i still need to declare the prototype in the .CC or its taken care of in the fmttime.h file.

Answer (score 6):

`#include`ing a file is literally a text replacement operation.  The contents of the header are just pasted directly into the file which includes it.

So, you can answer the question yourself.  Just imagine that the code in the header file *is actually in* the implementation file as well (because it is).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the layman termed explanation for the coding impaired such as I :) Actually I did have one more question if anyone could answer....in the function localtime() is my logic here correct as how this function is working?

First I am passing the pointer to the structure etime to the function. Therefore I am able to edit the objects inside the field of the expandedtime structure....then by saying "return etime" i am returning the edited version of that structure back to the main?

Comment: @user2163350: Yes, your reasoning there is correct.  However... why return it from the function?  Just make it clear that `etime` is expected to be a pointer to an allocated `ExpandedTime` object which is then populated and don't return anything.  It's very odd to pass in an argument which is expected to be mutated and receive a copy of it in return.

Comment: Yes I thought that was odd...it was more of a formality since Im not the best at coding.I found it odd that I was editing the contents of the ExpandedTime structure and then returning it again. As you said its already altering the fields of the structure.

However the function prototype expects a returned arguement which is ExpandedTime* so naturally I returned etime. So your saying to simply remove the return statement?  

I was under the impression that unless a function is void  then the return isnt needed...

Comment: @user2163350: You wrote the function prototype, right?  You can change it.  If, for some strange reason you cannot change it... you have to leave it as is I suppose.

Comment: Haha yes sorry about the confusion...but its part of a lab for school. therefore I have to use the prototypes he gives us.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are only #included into source files. They are not linked. After processing pre-processor directives, such as #include, the compiler will compile source code to an object file (.o). Then the object file(s) are passed to the linker for linking.

For your final question, I suggest you try compiling your .CC file without the #include directive and then #include the header file and compile again.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

.h/hpp -> function prototypes, variable/structs/enums definitions

.c/.cpp -> function implementations (.c/.cpp require including their corresponding headers)

Comment: Unless you're using templates